# Error:No module named 'mmengine' when trying to run mmsegmentation

Tags: python

I'm using ubuntu-2204,and cuda-toolkit-11.8.I downloaded mmsegmentation from github and tried to run a demo using

```
python demo/image_demo.py demo/demo.png configs/pspnet/pspnet_r50-d8_4xb2-40k_cityscapes-512x1024.py pspnet_r50-d8_512x1024_40k_cityscapes_20200605_003338-2966598c.pth --device cuda:0 --out-file result.jpg
```

as instructed.However I am comfronted with

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mmengine'
```

What confuses me is that i do have the package installed through mim as instructed:

```
mim list
```

and it shows:

```
mmcv            2.1.0      https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmcv
mmengine        0.10.2     https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmengine
mmsegmentation  1.2.2      /home/usr/GitRepo/mmsegmentation
```

I was totally confused and don't know what to do.
Can anyone help.Pwease:(

Comment: Have you tried uninstall and reinstall with `pip install -U openmim` as stated in [mmengine](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmengine)?

Comment: Sorry for delay and yes it did solve my problem!THX!:)